# converting an insert function using query method into a prepared statement

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code that does standard INSERTs.How can i rewrite this function to do the same but instead of using

```
$this->db->query($query)
```

i want it to be able to do the same by using a prepared statement because this code seems very vulnerable against SQL injection..Here is the code.

```
    private function insert($table, $arr){

        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (";
        $pref = "";

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $query .= $pref . $key;
                $pref = ", ";
            }
            $query .= ") VALUES (";
            $pref = "";
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $query .= $pref. "'" . $value . "'";
                $pref = ", ";
            }
            $query = .= ");";
            return $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

I am connected to mysql with PDO.

EDİT:I wrote the following code which works without a problem.

```
private function insert($table, $arr){

    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (";
    $pref = "";

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $query .= $pref . $key;
            $pref = ", ";
        }
        $query .= ") VALUES (";
        $pref = "";
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $query .= $pref. ":" . $key ;
            $pref = ", ";
        }
        $query .= ");";
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $result->execute($arr);
}
```

Comment: I want cookies. I tried going to the supermarket. You want a prepared statement with PDO. What have you tried?

Comment: well i know i have to change the VALUES part so it looks something like VALUES (:value, :value2, :value3...) and then i have to execute(); an array for the values and change the $this->db->query($query) part at the end to a prepared statement but i am having trouble putting it together.

Comment: hmm reading my question again i see that it seems like i am ordering people to do the work for me so i understand your comment.Sorry! that was not my intent and i didn't mean to write it that way.I just couldn't put it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php Example #1, try something like

```
private function insert($table, $arr){

    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (";
    $pref = "";

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $query .= $pref . $key;
            $pref = ", ";
        }
        $query .= ") VALUES (";
        $pref = "";
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $query .= $pref. ":" . $key;
            $pref = ", ";
        }
        $query = .= ")";
        $this->db->prepare($query);
        $this->db->execute($arr);

}
```